# Neo4j - N-gram - A node with a (distance > x) to all nodes in path

Tags: neo4j, cypher

How to find n-gram in neo4j cypher query?
N-gram : A sequence of words which are some distance or more(let say >=x), from all the previous nodes in the path.

Ex: choosing A as start node.

```
A -dist-> B, where dist(A,B)>=0.8 , one level
A -dist-> B -dist-> C, where dist(A,B)>=0.8,dist(A,C)>=0.8,dist(B,C)>=0.8
A -dist-> B -dist-> C -dist-> D, where dist(A,D)>=0.8, dist(B,D)>=0.8, dist(C,D)>=0.8
```

Which means, the distance between all the possible combines of nodes should be greater than the threshold(i.e., 0.8).

Here is my attempt:

```
MATCH p=(a{word:"quality"})-[r*1..2]->(b) 
WHERE NONE (n IN nodes(p) WHERE size(filter(x IN nodes(p) WHERE n = x))> 1)
AND ALL(rel IN rels(p) WHERE rel.val >= 1.5)
WITH p,size(rels(p))+1 AS nodes
RETRUN p,nodes ORDER BY nodes desc
```

In this query, the newly added nodes check only with the element which was previously added one.
Please suggest the changes in my query. Thanks.

Comment: Does your query work? What is the result?

Comment: Yes, That query returns a path where,all the relationship values are greater than x.